# Valgrind conditional jump

Tags: c++

So I have some code that works, but valgrind says that there is a conditional jump that depends on uninitialized value(s). I think I know what's causing this (see below) but I don't know of any alternatives/solutions.

```
class Vector{
    private:
        int maxLength;
        int *buffer;
        void error(char* msg){
            cerr << "Error: " << msg << endl;
        }

        bool inBounds(int i){
            return i>=0 && i < maxLength;
        }
public:
    Vector(int newLenth)
        : maxLength(newLenth), buffer(new int[newLenth])
        {
        }
    int & operator [] (int index){
        if (!inBounds(index)){
            error("Out of bounds");
        }
        return buffer[index];
    }

    int length(){
        int count =0;
        for (int i = 0; buffer[i];++i){
            count +=1;
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

I think the problem is that in the for loop, buffer[i] isn't "initialized". What should I do to fix this? (At a level of a c++ novice, please)

```
int main(){
    Vector v(10);
    v[0] = 1;
    cout << v.length() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Initialize the buffer after allocating it? `memset(buffer,0, sizeof(int) * newLenth);`

Comment: That would go after the initialization list, correct?

Also, I tried it and got an error saying memset was not declared in this scope.

Comment: It should go into constructor body , between {}. `memset` is declared at `memory.h` header. You need to include it into your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop progresses until it finds zero in the `buffer` array, i.e. it expects the buffer to be null-terminated. You place `1` into the initial element, but the element right after it remains uninitialized.

Placing zero into it will fix the problem:

```
Vector v(10);
v[0] = 1;
v[1] = 0;
cout << v.length() << endl;
```

**Note:** You should make your loop safe by terminating upon reaching `maxLength` as well:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != maxLength && buffer[i] ; ++i) {
    count++;
}
```

This will ensure that you do not probe positions past the end of the buffer for zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the buffer easily with

```
: maxLength(newLenth), buffer(new int[newLenth]{})
                                               ^^- note
```

That would make all elements (`maxLength` of them) in `buffer` initialized to `int` default value (which is `0`).